# "Pose" sculpting tool hides mesh in view port

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation

Using Blender 3.4.1, in sculpt mode I can successfully use the "Pinch", "Grab", "Elastic Deform", "Snake Hook", "Thumb", "Nudge" and "Rotate" tools to modify meshes. But as soon as I use the "Pose" tool, the mesh of the touched object completely vanishes from the view port (all untouched meshes stay visible). If I undo the "Pose" step, the mesh shows up again in the view port.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in 3.4.1. After installing 3.5 it works as it should, I guess there was a bug with the pose tool in this version of Blender.